# Regex (or similar approach) to match SQL Server field name that should be delimited

Tags: regex, vb.net, delimiter

I want to write a regex in VB.NET that takes a string and determines whether it should be delimited for it to be valid as a field name in SQL server.

For example, `myField` is valid (example context: `SELECT myField from myTable`), but `my field` is not and would need to be delimited with square brackets (`select [my field] from myTable`).

The regex should match a string containing any of the following:

- Whitespace characters
- Special characters (`!"£$%^` etc), not including `_`, `@`, `#`
- String *starting* with a number or `@`
- Any other field naming rules (not including sql reserved keywords, a separate function deals with that)

My current regex pattern is `[^A-Za-z]+`, which thereabouts works as it matches any non-alphabetical character, but it unecessarily matches names such as `my_field` or `field0`

**Regex answer is preferred, but other approaches are fine too**

Comment: Would you accept a non-Regex-based solution?

Comment: It would need to be fairly optimal (ie, not doing a ton of loops), but sure. A regex would be preferred though.

Comment: I anticipated to your answer. Take a look at what I wrote and let me know if it meets your expectations.

Comment: And well? Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a non-Regex-based solution.

```
Dim inputString As String = "my field"
If (fieldIsValid(inputString)) Then
    'Do anything
End If
```

Where `fieldIsValid` is a function defined by:

```
Private Function fieldIsValid(inputString As String) As Boolean
    Dim delimiters() As String = New String() {" ", "!", """", "£", "$", "%", "^"}
    If StringContains(inputString, delimiters) Then
        Return False
    End If

    If (IsNumeric(inputString.Substring(0, 1)) OrElse inputString.Substring(0, 1) = "@") Then 
        Return False
    End If

    Return True

End Function

Private Function StringContains(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal ParamArray delimiters() As String) As Boolean
    For Each delimiter In delimiters
        If inputString.Contains(delimiter) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next

    Return False
End Function
```

As you can see, the code-size difference with respect to a Regex-based solution is not too big this time; also this kind of solutions provide more flexibility if you want to improve/extend it in the future. Regarding "special characters" you would have to be more specific; even in case of using Regex, you would have to tell what you consider a special character.

Comment: That's nice - I edited to wrap that long `OrElse` chain into a separate function, but should suit my purposes for now.

Comment: @kai (you wanted everything regex-type and without loops and that's why I put everything in one line :)) People tend to think that the easiest way is regex but, "contains" and "split" provide also a quick and reliable solution for a big variety of cases; and this kind of approaches are more extensible/adaptable.

Comment: @kai two things: first thing is that I usually rely on loops, I wrote the condition because you let clear that you didn't want loops (and didn't want to scare you :)). Second thing: I have accepted your edit but will change it right now; you cannot edit the code of other person (much less without his permisson). Edits are for improving clearly wrong bits; my code wasn't wrong. Thanks for the help anyway ;)

Comment: The loop in this case is equivilant to an OrElse chain - like the OrElse chain, it steps through each character in turn until it finds one that matches, and then returns. The loop is syntactically prettier though :)

Comment: @kai please, read my comment and try to understand it properly: I know what your modification does; I wouldn't ever have written a so long list of OrElses; the only reason why I did it is because you said that you don't want loops. Remember I am the loop-guy (you are the one relying on regex and line-based statements), I only intended to write everything in a way you would find it more attractive. Actually I will improve what you wrote.

Comment: @Kai PS: even in case that you would be showing me something I haven't ever seen before, wasn't able to come up with (what I am afraid that is not the case), you CANNOT EDIT THE CODE OF OTHERS. The reason why I accepted you edit is because I do this most of the times with low-rep users: I guess that getting more and more edits is good for you.

Comment: @Kai No problem. Take a look at my edits: better use "for" when you need to track the given index; if you just need to look at the elements foreach is more friendly. Also when you call a function with an array don't do what you did: create the array, but don't rely on this kind of code which purely-speaking is not even right. You can even create the array while calling the function, example: StringContains(inputString, {" ", "!", """", "£", "$", "%", "^"}); this is a different thing than what you did.

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches your criteria:

```
^([\d@]|.*[^\w@#$]).*$
```

...and more! Rather than having to specify all invalud characters (there are 64K of them) this uses negation of characters that are valid.

There are really only two types of problem:

- the initial char
- the remaining chars

Whitespace does not need a special check - they are just done if the thousands of non-valid characters.

Because you want a regex that matches what's *invalid*, the two types of problem are ORed.